# Can you create numbers around the analog clock?

Tags: processing

so, as an assaignment i want to make an analog clock, and i am pretty far. I only need the numbers around the clock, but i cant figure out how to make these. I have made some dots right now, but i want to replace theese with the numbers 1-12.. does any1 know an easy and fast way of doing this? my code is as following:

````
let cx, cy;
let secondsRadius;
let minutesRadius;
let hoursRadius;
let clockDiameter;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(800, 800);
  let radius= min(width,height)/2;
  secondsRadius=radius*0.71;
  minutesRadius = radius*0.6;
  hoursRadius = radius*0.5;

  clockDiameter = radius*1.7;
  cx = width/2;
  cy = height/2;
}

function draw() {
  background("pink");

  noStroke();
  fill(244, 122, 158);
  ellipse(cx, cy, clockDiameter + 25, clockDiameter + 25);
  fill("green");
  ellipse(cx,cy,clockDiameter, clockDiameter);
 
  let s = map(second(), 0, 60, 0, TWO_PI) - HALF_PI;
  let m = map(minute() + norm(second(), 0, 60), 0, 60, 0, TWO_PI) - HALF_PI;
  let h = map(hour() + norm(minute(), 0, 60), 0, 24, 0, TWO_PI *2) -        HALF_PI;
 
  stroke(255);
  strokeWeight(1);
  line(cx, cy, cx + cos(s) * secondsRadius, cy + sin(s) * secondsRadius);
  strokeWeight(2);
  line(cx, cy, cx + cos(m) * minutesRadius, cy + sin(m) * minutesRadius);
  strokeWeight(4);
  line(cx, cy, cx + cos(h) * hoursRadius, cy + sin(h) * hoursRadius);
  strokeWeight(2);

  beginShape(POINTS);
  for (let a = 0; a < 360; a += 6) {
     let angle = radians(a);
     let  x = cx + cos(angle) * secondsRadius;
     let  y = cy + sin(angle) * secondsRadius;
     vertex(x, y);
  }
  endShape();
}```
````

Comment: Are you using p5.js? Example of creating analog clock with digits is [here](https://editor.p5js.org/tamserad/sketches/jIbrj4-gs)  or [here](https://openprocessing.org/sketch/387974/)

Comment: Nope. I am just trying to  make a number hand in the following code not changing the whole code. Thanks for your time and your suggestion :)

Comment: https://github.com/alaksandarjesus/simple-analog-clock

Answer (score 2):

As a quick and dirty:) answer - **just add** something like that *before the last brace*:

```
  textSize(36);
  fill("white");
  noStroke()
  for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    v = p5.Vector.fromAngle((i + 1) / 12.0 * TAU - HALF_PI);
    v.mult(310);
    text(i + 1, 382 + v.x, 416 + v.y);
  }
```

My live working demo (**your code** + this addition) is on [ReplIt](https://replit.com/@Babich/temporary)

Comment: Hi it dosent work i have tried it too.

Comment: Do you tried my [live demo](https://replit.com/@Babich/temporary) based on your code (look at script.js file - this is *exactly your code* with this addition)? It works perfectly for me!

Comment: Here is the result - https://temporary.babich.repl.co/